# Is it possible to use ISelenium/DefaultSelenium without installing Selenium Server?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I used IWebDriver to control IE for testing before.  But the methods supported for IWebDriver and IWebElement are so limited.  I find that ISelenium/DefaultSelenium which belongs to Selenium namespace are very useful.  How can I use them to control an IE without installing the Selenium Server??

Here's the constructor of DefaultSelenium:

```
ISelenium sele = new DefaultSelenium(**serveraddr**, **serverport**, browser, url2test);
sele.Start();
sele.Open();
...
```

Seems that I have to install Selenium Server before I create an ISelenium object.

My case is, I'm trying to build a .exe application with C#+Selenium which can run on different PCs and it's impossible to install Selenium Server on all PCs(you never know which one is the next to run the app).

Does anyone know how to use ISelenium/DefaultSelenium without installing the server?
thx!

Comment: If you use WebDriver (Selenium 2), it doesn't need to start Selenium Server

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions in Java without using the RC Server:

**1)** For the selenium browser startup:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("safari");
CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(new URL("http://localhost:4444/"), new URL("http://www.google.com/"), capabilities);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, capabilities);
```

**2)** For selenium commands:

```
// You may use any WebDriver implementation. Firefox is used here as an example
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// A "base url", used by selenium to resolve relative URLs
 String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";

// Create the Selenium implementation
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);

// Perform actions with selenium
selenium.open("http://www.google.com");
selenium.type("name=q", "cheese");
selenium.click("name=btnG");

// Get the underlying WebDriver implementation back. This will refer to the
// same WebDriver instance as the "driver" variable above.
WebDriver driverInstance = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver();

//Finally, close the browser. Call stop on the WebDriverBackedSelenium instance
//instead of calling driver.quit(). Otherwise, the JVM will continue running after
//the browser has been closed.
selenium.stop();
```

Descripted here: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Google for something similar in C#.
Theres no other way to achieve that.

Comment: Coretek, it works well on my side.  Thx a lot! Appreciate for your help !

Comment: I have one more question.  What does this mean? "WebDriver driverInstance = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver();" I don't understand.